# how can i convert a string with + and \n to an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, object

This is my input and I want a function for converting it to an object:

```
var filecontent = "22,david\n" + "25,jack\n" + "19,jason\n" + "18,peter\n";
```

How can I convert it to this object?

```
let obj = {
  "22":"david",
  "25":"jack",
  "19":"jason",
  "18":"peter"
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your attempt so far?

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
var filecontent = "22,david\n" + "25,jack\n" + "19,jason\n" + "18,peter\n";
```

replace all `,` and `\n` to make it a json format

```
filecontent = filecontent.replaceAll(",",'":"').replaceAll("\n",'","')
```

remove the extra characters from the string

```
filecontent= filecontent.substring(0, filecontent.length - 2);
```

add the missing `{"` , `}` to make a valid json

```
filecontent='{"'+filecontent+'}';
```

the using JSON.parse to convert the string to obj

```
var obj = JSON.parse(filecontent);
```

Comment: this is true but i want the object to be like what i said 
what you said has an output like this 
{18: "peter", 19: "jason", 22: "david", 25: "jack"}
i want an output like
let obj = {
  "22":"david",
  "25":"jack",
  "19":"jason",
  "18":"peter"
}

Comment: The JavaScript console may display this as 22:"david" (not wrapped in quotes), but if we check its type we'll see that it is actually a string

Comment: for (var key in obj)
    console.log(typeof key);